# Sum of specific numbers and rounding numbers to two decimal places

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get the sum of certain numbers from a file without changing the file itself

```
1 #person number
Marlon Holmes  #Name
18.86 # First number
13.02 # Second Number
13.36 # Third Number
```

For the sum of numbers, it needs to be the #First, #second and #third number

The numbers currently are in cm which have been converted to inches which the two decimal places are necessary for

My code at present is to provide the top 3 people based on the sum of the #first,#second and #third numbers.

Current code:

```
data = []
names = OrderedDict([('Competitor Number', int),
    ('Competitor Name', str),
    ('Cucumber', to_inch),
    ('Carrot', to_inch),
    ('Runner Bean', to_inch)])

with open('veggies_2016.txt') as fobj:
    while True:
        item = {}
        try:
            for name, func in names.items():
                item[name] = func(next(fobj).strip())
            data.append(item)
        except StopIteration:
            break
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('Runner Bean'), reverse = True)
for entry in sorted_data[:3]:
    for key, value in entry.items():
        print value
    print
```

There are about 50 records in the file that im reading from, which the sum must be added up for all then put in order to find the top 3 and ideally in two decimal places

Code referring to to_inch:

```
def to_inch(cm):
    return float(cm) / 2.54
```

The whole document works around a main menu

To get the sum, I have tried `sum(item.entry.items())` but with no success and have also tried `"%.2f"` for the decimal figures/significant figures but with no success, any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's `"%.2f"` by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we disregard reading from the file for now and assume we can put the numbers in a `list` we can use Python's [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round), [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

**Code:**

```
numbers = [18.86, 13.02, 13.36]

def to_inch(cm):
    return cm/2.54

numbers_in_inches = list(map(to_inch, numbers))
print(numbers_in_inches)

numbers_rounded = list(map(round, numbers_in_inches, [0 for _ in numbers]))
print(numbers_rounded)

sum_numbers = sum(numbers_rounded)
print(sum_numbers)
```

**Output:**

```
[7.4251968503937, 5.125984251968504, 5.259842519685039]
[7.0, 5.0, 5.0]
17.0
```

**What is happening:**

1. Mapped your function `to_inch` on each of the items in the list `numbers`
2. Mapped Python's `round()` function onto each the values in `numbers_in_inches`, the reasoning for the list comprehension on the end is it creates a list of `0`'s for `map()` to use for `round(number, places)`'s `places`.
3. Uses Python's `sum()` to take the sum of all of the numbers, of course, you can just use `round(sum_numbers, 0)` if you want to round after the sum. *Note:* If you want to round **after** you sum, use `math.fsum` instead of `sum` as mentioned by Copperfield in the comments.

**Now to parse the file:**

```
import re

numbers_names = {}
numbers = []
player_number = ''
name = ''

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '#person number' in line:
            player_number = int(line.split('#')[0])
        elif '#Name' in line:
            name = line.split('#')[0]
        else:
            line_numbers = re.sub(r"[^\d.]", "", line)
            if '.' in line_numbers:
                numbers.append(float(line_numbers))
        if len(numbers) >= 3 and player_number and name:
            numbers_names.update({'player_number': player_number, 'name': name,  'numbers': numbers})
            numbers, player_number, name = [], 0, ''

print(numbers_names)
```

**Output:**

```
{'name': 'Marlon Holmes  ', 'numbers': [18.86, 13.02, 13.36], 'player_number': 1}
```

**How It's parsing the file:**

1. First opens the file.
2. Next iterates over each line in the file.
3. For each line in the file, it sees whether it's a line containing the player's name, the players number, or the numbers that he has.

   - **Player Number** Splits line into the note and the data then takes the data and sets it equal to `player_number`.
   - **Name** Splits line into the note and the data then takes the data and sets it equal to `name`
   - **Numbers He Has** It removes all non-word characters except for `.` in the file using `re`'s `re.sub()`. Then, checks to see if there is a decimal in the cleaned-up line. Finally, if so it appends the line to `numbers`.
4. If all three values are present, it appends them all to the `numbers_names` dictionary and resets the variables for the next player.

Comment: How would i get this to work with all the numbers coming from the file?

Comment: Parse the file and put all the numbers into a list called `numbers`.

Comment: @NeilHouston Updated

Comment: @NeilHouston you can add the rounding part to `to_inch` like this: `return round( float(cm)/2.54, 2)` where the 2 is if you want 2 decimal places, or any other number that you want

Comment: to minimize the floating point rounding issue you can use [`math.fsum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.fsum) instead of sum

Comment: @Copperfield If they have already been rounded there isn't much of a point.

Comment: @Signal I am unable to to get it to sum the numbers still from the file

Comment: @NeilHouston Please provide a little detail

Comment: @Signal At the moment it just rounds the numbers, nothing else

Comment: @Signal the part which you have named code and parsing the file

Comment: For each player just use the  `numbers` output from that piece, and put it into the first wall of code In the post....

Comment: @Signal perhaps, but I think the OP wanted 2 decimal places of presicion and even with round number floating point aritmetic can be annoying depending in how much precision you want, take for example: `sum([1.01, 10.1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1]) #11.609999999999998` vs `math.fsum([1.01, 10.1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1])#11.61`

Comment: @Copperfield I see what you mean now, I added a note that If he wants to round after he sums he should use `math.fsum`.